# Html drop down list for many options

Tags: html, templates

Beginner flasker....I would like to create an html form whereby the user selects from many options. I can do this successfully as below for 4 options:

```
<form action="", method="POST">
     <dl>
         <dt>Agent:
         <br>
         <select id="soflow" name="Agent" required >
         <option value = "Daniel">Daniel</option>
         <option value = "Tuliswa">Tuliswa</option>
         <option value = "Pamella">Pamella</option>
         <option value = "Mzukisi">Mzukisi</option>
         </select><br><br>
     </dl)
```

But how would I do this if I need the list to be much longer (up to 100 options), without entering each option as above? For example, a list to select country of birth?

Comment: Are you searching for an answer related to templating? Because currently your question has nothing to do specifically with Python or Flask.

Comment: edited to `html` + `templates`

Comment: you need to create an array of your data and loop through to output the option. How do you get the data at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you originally had it tagged with Flask, I'm assuming you're using Jinja for templating.

You could have a template like this:

```
<select id="soflow" name="Agent" required>
    {% for option in options %}
        <option value="{{ option }}">{{ option }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Then when you call `render_template("template.html")`, you instead call it like this:

```
options = [
    "Daniel",
    "Tuliswa",
    "Pamella",
    "Mzukisi",
    # ...
]

render_template("template.html", options=options)
```

This now gives you the option to get all the options from a file or datebase.